# I have a problem with running projects with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to learn java from a youtube tutorial and i can't even figure out the first lesson because i keep getting a wierd error when i try to run my code. **Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: E:\Eclipse\workspace\Hello\bin
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: MySweetProgram.class found in top-level directory (unnamed package not allowed in module)**
This is the error. Can anybody please help?

Tried to run my code and i am not able to find out why it's not working